# dompdf - PDF file corrupt when FE compressionLevel is set

Tags: compression, typo3, dompdf, extbase

I have an extbase extension where I have a createPdfAction in which I create a PDF from the current view.

looks kinda like this:

```
    $html = $this->view->render();
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    $dompdf->loadHtml(utf8_decode($html));

    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($this->clearString('filename.pdf');
    exit;
```

Works great, but if i set the FE compressionLevel e.g. to 5 in the install tool - the PDF File which is created is now corrupt and can't be opened.

I even tried to turn off the compression by dompdf itself:

```
$dompdf->stream($this->clearString('filename.pdf',array("compress" => 0));
```

But that also didn't work

---

dompdf 0.8.0

TYPO3 8.7.1

php 7

Comment: Check the `Content-Encoding` header of the HTTP response. If it sets a compression, the streamed file must be compressed using the correct compression method. If it is not set, it must not be compressed. Is there a mismatch? Maybe TYPO3 sends out a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header, but dompdf sends an uncompressed PDF, which produces an error when the browser tries to uncompress it.

Comment: I got no response header or similar like that - but a request header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`

Comment: But if I enter following in the .htacces I get the Content-Encoding header:
`Addtype application/pdf .pdf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/pdf`
but still no change

Comment: Try to add a `header('Content-Encoding: gzip')` just before doing the streaming - maybe that helps. Also download the streamed file, and check if it compressed somehow, and try to identify the compression algorithm (probably gzip). In case adding the header works, you must make sure that the file is sent uncompressed if thhe `Accept-Encoding` does not contain `gzip` as allowed algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Jost](https://stackoverflow.com/users/752701/jost):

Adding `header('Content-Encoding: gzip')` fixes the problem.

Comment: Make sure the header is only added if the requests `Accept-Encoding`-header contains `gzip`. Otherwise the download will be broken again. Also, uncompress the streamed result if gzip is no accepted encoding.